# Function (in different files with same name and argument) calling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have two seprate .JS files i.e. abc.js and xyz.js, in both JS files I have one method like:

**abc.js**

```
function OpenPopup(url){
//Code
}
```

**xyz.js**

```
function OpenPopup(url){
// some different implementation
}
```

Then I have inculde these two files on a HTML page like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="abc.js" id="file1"> </script>
<script src="xyz.js" id="file2"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="OpenPopup(url)">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to open function on some event say onclick of any button (like above) then,

**1)** *Which method of which files gets called i.e. OpenPopup of abc.js or OpenPopup of xyz.js as in both files function name and its argument are same?*

**2)** *If, say OpenPopup of abc.js called. Then how explicitly I can call the OpenPopup function  of xyz.js file?*

Comment: Using `<script src="abc.js" id="file1"/>` is like place the code inside `abc.js` right here. You can't call any function from that file by using the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working on the same two weeks ago, turns out that the last function loaded will override the others, you can't really predict witch one will override the other as the scripts are not loading synchronously but in perfect cases, the last function contained in the last script will override.

Now about loading functions following the file name, I've tried a "namespacing" technique, I've managed to make something like this :

Script abc.js

```
var abc = function(){
return {
    OpenPopup : function(){
        //Code goes here
    }
}
}
```

Script xyz.js

```
var xyz = function(){
return {
    OpenPopup : function(){
        //Code goes here
    }
}
```

}

You'll be able to call OpenPopup like this :

```
abc().OpenPopup();
xyz().OpenPopup();
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Tarek, I've also tried doing same and you're right that since loading of javascript file is not synchronously, so whichever files gets load last will override the function.

Comment: Regarding #2 query, that can be achieved by function literals.

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally the last one to be defined will be the one that gets called. In this case, since you haven't got an end tag for your `<script>` element, the second script won't be parsed at all.
2. You can't. By defining a new function with the same name as an existing function, in the same scope as that function, you have overwritten it and it will be garbage collected.

Comment: I have corrected the closing script tag. If say both files get parsed then what will happen?

Comment: Then, as I said, the last one you define will overwrite the first one and that will be the one that will be called.

Comment: OK, thanks Quentin, this answer my first question. Regarding second query, I think that can be achieve by function literals.

Answer (score 1):

u may try this (not tested):

**abc.js:**

```
(function(window, document){
  function OpenPopup(url){
    //Code
  }
  window.abc = {};
  window.abc.OpenPopup = OpenPopup;
})(window, document);
```

**xyz.js:**

```
(function(window, document){
  function OpenPopup(url){
    //Code
  }
  window.xyz = {};
  window.xyz.OpenPopup = OpenPopup;
})(window, document);
```

**html**

```
<button onclick="abc.OpenPopup(url)">Try abc.js</button>
<button onclick="xyz.OpenPopup(url)">Try xyz.js</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, This is a general query. I have just name the function OpenPopup. My actual query is what exactly will happen in such kind of scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to close your  tag as  will not work here.
Secondly, you are only overwriting your method under the same scope.
Lastly, your code will through error also as in the functional call you have not defined 'url' so the error will be raised that url is undefined.

Correct code is given below:
    
    
    
    
    
    
    Try it

Comment: This is general query, I'm just presented one scenario that in such kind of scenario what will happen? I hope you'll get my point.